# What does the phrase "そうくるんですか" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

This is the first time I've come across such a phrase (in a novel) and I couldn't find an explanation through an internet search.

Comment: Context please?

Comment: @kuchitsu in the novel character A (Nikolai) has offered character B (Risa) a secret weapon. Risa is a private investigator and is hesitant about receiving the secret weapon, but she decides to take it and says it might help in her investigations later. Nikolai then says "そうくるんですか?"

Comment: If you're familiar with そうこなくっちゃ, I think they are closely related.

Comment: @kuchitsu yeah I've heard of that phrase before, it means something along the lines of "now you're talking", but the phrase I gave is a question, how would I work this into a question if the meanings are similar?

Comment: Providing some context **in the original language** often helps ensure the quality of the answers you get.  The longer the question, the better the answer-- usually.  My little comment is already longer than your question and that is not very  ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the following situation that Alice and Bob play Japanese chess. Alice expected what Bob do next, but Bob's next move was beyond her expectations.Then, maybe Alice said そうくるんですか to Bob.  
そうくるか/そうくるんですか/そうきたか are used when something unexpected happened to narrator. Also, そうこなくっちゃ means that’s what I wanted to hear.

Comment: Using 将棋 as an example is great ^^

Answer (score 0):

In this case a direct parallel English expression comes to mind:

> "So it has come to that"
>
> そう(that)くる(come to)んです[explanatory]か

But as other users have pointed out, you should provide better context or no one will be able to give you a satisfying answer.